# How does curl separate data to send?

Tags: c++, http, curl, winsock

I'm writing an HTTP server with C++ `WinSock` sockets, I use `recv` to receive data from *curl* via TCP stream. When I send small files everything works fine, but with bigger files curl seems to split data and send parts separately as the returned value of `recv` in this case is only equal to the size of the HTTP header whereas on the client side curl fails to receive a response. This makes me assume curl can split data into a header and a body if the amount of data is too big, but I cannot find any docs which would confirm it.

In order to adjust my server to receive any data from curl, I need to know how curl sends it.

Does curl split big data to send? How many parts should I expect?

Comment: You should **NEVER EVER** assume anything based on how many bytes a single call to `recv` returns. The HTTP protocol has very specific rules on how to pass data. First you need to read headers based on the "headers end with double /r/n" rule (for that you will need to loop `recv()` calls until you find the mark or it exceeds some limit of your choice). Then you parse headers, read the `Content-Length` header (if present, if not things get more complicated) and finally read the body by looping recv calls based no that value. That's how HTTP works, and CURL has to obey it.

Comment: @freakish I already have an HTTP parser, the thing is I start to parse the buffer only when all the data receives. And here sometimes I receive a header and a body in one shot, sometimes not. It is not a problem to parse the header first and then to proceed to receiving the body, but how will I know if I already received it

Comment: I've already explained that: "headers end with double /r/n". You need to loop recv() calls until you find that special sequence of chars in the buffer. Let me give you a final piece of advice: do not write your own HTTP parser, this task is tedious, hard, time consuming and error prone. HTTP is hard.

Comment: There's no way to receive a whole HTTP response without parsing it as you go along, you need to be able to handle `recv` returning the response split into arbitrary chunks, this is usually done with some sort of buffering

Comment: TCP - the protocol used by cURL and most of the internet - can split your message.  Any call to `recv` (regardless of whether it came from cURL) should be written to account for the possibility that the data received is not the complete message that was sent.

Comment: In general, a streaming protocol like TCP, which HTTP is built upon, prioritizes data delivery and order over pretty much everything else. It pays no attention to the user's messages and views them as a sequences of bytes to be sent however it sees fit so long as the bytes are delivered to the receiving code in the same order they were sent. You will see multiple messages arriving at the same time, fragments of messages arriving at the same time, huge gaps in time between data that's part of the same message, and all manner of nastiness.

Comment: @freakish I only need my parser to process a single request, I'm not going to provide full HTTP support, I'll just issue something like a bad request if the request does not correspond to what I expect. I've never worked with HTTP, so it is easier for me to grab some basic knowledge for what exactly I need rather that seek a good parser and learn it. My deadline is coming :)

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter. The message ends when the carriage-return-line-feed arrives. No sooner and no later. If you don't read through to the end of the message, you can't be sure you got the whole message. The very minimum you must do is keep calling `recv` until you find the end. It could all be in one packet, it could be in 20. It could arrive in milliseconds, It could take a week.

Comment: @Kaiyakha listen, youre telling me what you want, and I'm telling you how HTTP works and how your approach will never get you there. Use a framework. That's all I have to say about the topic.

Comment: @freakish I know it is a bit weird approach, but I have no time to mess around with frameworks I've never worked with, anyway I got your point

Comment: "I use `recv` to receive data from curl" is nonsensical. It doesn't matter what the sending end is, TCP is an *unstructured* stream of octets, and `recv` can produce any amount of that stream, or nothing at all, each time you call it. This is covered in any half-decent introduction to TCP sockets.

Comment: @Kaiyakha see my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on the kind of logic you need to implement to receive and parse HTTP messages *correctly*. Most of them are geared towards a client receiving+parsing a server's response, but similar logic applies to a server receiving+parsing a client's request, too.

Comment: OK, as far as I've got this I first need to loop `recv` until I've come across `\r\n\r\n`, then I parse the header, read the amount of data from `content-length` (if any) and loop `recv` until the amount of data returned from `recv` matches `content-length`, right?

Comment: That's how it begins. Then there are hundreds of edge cases: what if one recv() returns `\r\n\r` and the next one starts with `\n`? You need proper buffering. What if you read more than just headers in one go, i.e. a piece of body as well? What if the request is malformed and there is no `Content-Length` header? What if there is but actually is not correct?Are headers case sensitive? What about values? What if the client disconnects randomly? Don't be stubborn, take my advice and use a framework. You have no time for framework but you have time dealing with hundreds of such issues? Ridiculous.

Comment: @freakish now everything is working, thanks! My request has `header_size` and `content_length` attributes. In case the body is empty, `content_length` is 0. First I looped `recv` until I found `\r\n\r\n` (do while), then I parsed the header and looped `recv` again `while (stride < request.header_size + request.content_length)` where `stride` is init with 0 and accumulates the amount of bytes from every `recv` including the first loop. In case `content_length` is 0 or all the data has been received in the first loop, this loop will never be entered. What do you thing?

Comment: @freakish all you have pointed out is quite obvious. Of course I know that `recv` may receive past header, of course I took care about whether `content-length` is absent at all, of course I lowered the case when parsing the buffer (even before posting this), don't take me for such a dummy :)

Comment: @Kaiyakha I'm pretty sure you are not aware of how complicated HTTP is. We didn't even touch HTTP 2 and 3. Not to mention TLS, your approach is not secure at all. Btw if it is only for you to make a request, then why bother with HTTP? Just use any of much simpler protocols out there.

Comment: `Content-Length: 0` means that there is no body, so you don't have to read anything. Unless there's a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header (in that case `Content-Length` should not be present at all), which makes things more complicated.

Comment: @freakish `request.content_length` is calculated in accordance with whether the corresponding attribute is found or not. And as I said, if it's 0, I do not read anythin (while loop is never entered)

Comment: @freakish as for HTTP itself, I know it's complicated, but for now I have no time to dive into it. This is my employment task: write an HTTP server which receives an image from CURL and sends back a mirrored image. I'm also writing it on Windows but must make sure it is buildable on Linux. Think of it: I have one week to make it work and no experience in Linux or HTTP at all. Should I waste half a week trying to find an easy-to-build and learn and 100% crossplatform framework, or should I just write a simple parser which is only supposed to respond to one request known well in advance?

Comment: @Kaiyakha yes, you should spent one day learning a framework instead of writing a parser. Especially when you have no experience with HTTP. Are you serious? Btw why do you even bother with C++? Such simple task can be done in 5 lines in Python. With C++ everything is 10 times harder.

Comment: @freakish because this is what they want me to do, make HTTP in C++. Such frameworks in C++ are not that easy even to build or find references/tutorials for, let alone learning it. It is not a matter of one day. Believe or not, it is way easier to spend a couple of hours learning basics of HTTP and write a simple parser that deal with HTTP frameworks in cpp

Answer (score 0):

> And here sometimes I receive a header and a body in one shot, **sometimes not**.

You server must parse headers upon receiving an empty header line `\r\n`. If there is the header `Expect: 100-continue`, the server should send a HTTP response with the status `100 Continue` to inform an uploading client about being ready to receive a content. `curl` will not send large data after headers until the required response is received. *"Sometimes not"* happens because your server does not follow this rule.